# What is my mistake here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067755/how-to-efficiently-find-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-from-its-roots) and described my approach in English in the question details.

User *X* comments that I should show him my code if I want to see his code. I tell him that just as I described my approach, he could tell me his more-efficient approach if he doesn't want to show me the code.

To this, another user *Y* says that I have not tried anything before posting a question.

After this, I finally convert the English to C++ and add the code to the question details.

I did not receive a response from either *X* or *Y* after this, but did get two downvotes. What could I have done better?

Comment: @TinyGiant Actually, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33067755) is a question asking for the right algorithm, code does not help.

Comment: The only comment on the post which is constructive to my question has nothing to do with the presence of my code in the question details. Its algorithm is VERY different from mine. Also, the code is a direct implementation of what I've said, it involves nothing except for simple loops.

Comment: Well, sometimes those commenting/voting are just wrong. Such happens (I'm out of votes).

Comment: At this point, after what sounds like useful peer review, the question looks genuinely useful.  And not all SO questions pass that test!  But if your question is covered in [MBo's link to a previous SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537120/sum-of-multiplication-of-all-combination-of-m-element-from-an-array-of-n-element/23537841#23537841), then perhaps the question should be closed as duplicate.  You might help us determine that.

Comment: Well, lesson learned, next time just post the snippet right away instead of SO users having to ask for it.  It is *important*.

Comment: @HansPassant I remember you ranting somewhere about people ruining your main SO page by bumping old (and obsolete) questions but it is not searchable since it was deleted. Do you remember that one? I wanted to use your answer as an example for others but I was not able to find it :(

Comment: Second lesson learned: after improving the question you must have patience; if the question has become a good and useful one, the upvotes will eventually trickle in. There is nothing wrong with the two initial downvotes, they were cast for the unimproved version with good reason.

Comment: Don't assume that the people that commented are necessarily the ones that downvoted.

Comment: @mason ...and some downvotes are not justifiable at all. I think there are users which downvote largely at random just because "they can". That is why I would find it a good idea to give a reason when downvoting.

Comment: @syck Sure, it's a good idea to give a reason. But you don't get to determine whether a downvote is justifiable. It's up to the person doing the voting. And no, I don't think there's many people that downvote just because they can. Just because you don't understand their reasoning doesn't mean they're just doing it for giggles.

Comment: @mason Adding a reason would increase expenditure on downvoting which would move it away from being just a single click. Look at Paul's answer below: One downvote, but no negative comment. On "my" themes (especially PHP) sometimes there seem to appear a bunch of downvotes on subsequent questions within a short time, that is what made me first think of that. I did not talk about _many_ people. On the other hand, providing a reason when downvoting (may it be even a boilerplate one) might provide other insights as well. And the thoughtful voter won't mind, I think.

Comment: I encountered this one early on. The problem is it's a duplicate of the mathoverflow question but we can't close it as a dupe to that one.

Comment: @syck _"On "my" themes (especially PHP) sometimes there seem to appear a bunch of downvotes on subsequent questions within a short time, that is what made me first think of that. "_ Did it occur to you that there is a large number of users online and they "all" monitor mostly the new questions tab? Would you be happy if you got a popup saying "It has been less than 5 seconds since someone downvoted on this site, please wait 5 seconds for a new slot to become available, or until a downvote has been reverted, whichever comes first"?

Comment: Your question implies that you've already got a straightforward but inefficient solution. While I disagree with your commenter's "show me yours and I'll show you mine" rhetoric, it would have behooved you to at least sketch out the solution that you already had. The plain-English description of the mathematical formula was IMVHO not enough.

Comment: @syck: Remember that comments aren't for justifying yourself, but for suggesting improvements to the post or asking for clarification. Also, even if you think a vote was unjustifiable, only vote on the posts merits, not on the votes. Countervoting degrades the usefulness of all votes.

Comment: My point was to emphasize that sometimes downvotes are not understandable, even more to new users. Of course there are many low-quality questions, but downvoting without a comment or (easier) providing a reason on the vote gives away a chance of learning. Template reasons could be "not understandable", "outdated", "incomplete" and the like. There is also a phenomenon of even useful questions "downvoted into oblivion", being sometimes referred to in the discussion about SO teams. Have also a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [new user tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the goal of Stack Overflow is to **"build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"**, and the incentives and disincentives that exist with points and badges are mostly in furthering this goal. The incentives system is imperfect and sometimes unfair, but for the most part works well.  There is a bit of bait and switch that goes on where people with questions show up believing we are here to answer any question, whatever it may be, regardless of quality or scope or topicality. But that's not true, and as you can see there is some prodding and sometimes unpleasant downvoting that occurs to improve quality.

Peer review is a deliberate part of SO's design, and criticism is essential feedback for editing a question.  Otherwise, how will you know what is needed to improve the question?  Even algorithmic questions could benefit from some source code to see what format the inputs are in and further pin down exactly what you are trying to do.

There is a common knee-jerk response for most people to reject criticism. It is natural and never really goes away.  It takes time to comprehend criticism, and that comprehension is slower than the knee-jerk response, and takes repetition to get de-sensitized and learn to respect the other side.

Consider whether chatter about the question could continue indefinitely in comments without performing any edits.  Surely, it could. You admit this was your initial response, and is a common experience here.  Making an edit in the face of criticism or downvoting can sometimes feel like surrendering to an (unfair?) attack or threat (sometimes seemingly from someone who enjoys downvoting or is less knowledgeable).  And, it is easier to chat than to write code or reformat code for posting.  Downvoting, while not an enjoyable experience for the poster, provides a credible threat that the question might be considered junk, receive less views, and not be answered at all.  A downvote or two is a fairly strong incentive to improve a question.

Improving a question does not always reverse downvotes because the downvoters are not notified when a question is edited. There are other reasons too, such as difference of opinion, but the lack of notification is arguably a design flaw in Stack Overflow and [notifying downvoters of edits has been suggested as a feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c).  So it is possible that the two downvoters moved on to other activities and might never revisit the question to see if you improved it. It is easy to argue "that's unfair", but fairness is secondary to quality here and it is how the site and community currently behave.  Downvotes can be countered by upvotes as is now occurring for this question.

Your question looks genuinely useful, which is the best praise I can offer.  A quick google for "polynomial from roots stack overflow"  didn't find a duplicate on the first page.

Comment: I think that's well put, _"There is a common knee-jerk response for most people to reject criticism. It is natural and never really goes away."_ However, like you mentioned, the merits system is imperfect - there are issues with the "I downvote because it's a poor question in my opinion, but I never justify my opinion in a comment" case. You mentioned a possible fix, but this issue plays into your comment about rejecting criticism. A user is more apt to accept criticism if instead of someone saying, "That question is bad" they say, "That question is bad because..."

Comment: nice emphasis that the goal is a knowledgebase, not personal affirmation

Comment: @Paul well said,I was thinking that maybe a good approach would be to also to add a grading system to questions/answers on their **Difficulty** which is influenced by a separate voting. Reason I say this, is I have noticed, when looking at members SO scores,  that some member get lots of SO credit by answering basic questions. Difficulty voting would help filter out the knowledgeable vs less knowledgeable, as currently using members SO is almost meaningless when all they are answering is questions like "what is the length of my string?" over and over and finally achieving a really hi So score.

Comment: @Paul I think you should edit / omit the first line. I never proposed that the goal of SO is anything close to "determining fault". That's the goal of meta.so, since it "is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow the company and the software that runs the Stack Exchange Q&A network".

And I'm not here to ask for praises about my question, only to understand how to best make use of and contribute to the platform.

Comment: @anukul Although it's been 3 years since all this was posted, I removed the first line as you recently requested.

Answer (score 31):

For better or worse, SO questions that don't contain *any* code tend to be seen as lacking effort, especially if they look like they could be homework questions. When some SO regulars see such questions they are likely to down-vote & move on without giving the question much thought. And to be honest, the first two versions of your question *are* rather minimal.

(FWIW, my policy is to use comments to encourage authors to improve their question; I only down-vote or vote to close when the author doesn't (or can't) improve the question, and I *do* up-vote questions that were initially poor when the author improves the question's quality).

We don't expect question code to be perfect (if it *were* perfect, you wouldn't be asking a question :) ), but if we can see *some* code, we know that you have put in *some* effort.

Of course, that's not the only reason we like to see code in questions. Code (with sample input & output data) can often help us understand a problem better than a verbal description. And seeing your code can give us an idea of your level of understanding of the problem domain, and how advanced your coding skills are, both of which can help us to write an answer that's appropriate for your needs (and hopefully, also of use to future readers). Also, it's nice to be able to use the question code as the foundation for an answer, rather than having to write the whole thing from scratch. (For further info on this topic, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

As Deduplicator said, your question was really asking about an algorithm; using the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag may have deflected some of those down-votes; OTOH, some people don't realise that algorithm questions *are* on-topic for SO. But even with algorithm questions, I believe that a little bit of code or pseudo-code will make your question more acceptable in the eyes of many.

Comment: So is the purpose of StackOverflow to look like we're trying hard, or to develop a database of useful programming questions?  I am confused.

Comment: @hoodaticus: We're building a repository of useful _answers_ to programming questions. People don't come to SO to read the questions (apart from us poor benighted fools who feel impelled to answer said questions), they come here for the answers. And to get the best answers you need good-quality questions, as discussed by Jeff Atwood in [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand).

Comment: good answer, thank you