# Why don't I get useful answers to my questions anymore?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have not used Stack Overflow for about two years now. It used to be the most lively, exciting and challenging problem solving environment for programmers around the world. It used to be fast and effective. It was useful.

Now I have returned to ask **some programming questions**, mainly about C++11 and UML. I was waiting eagerly for a professional, academic level argumentation based on bulletproof definitions that would lead myself to the inevitable conclusion that I could accept as an answer. Or at least a useful solution. Solution would suffice...

There are only three words to describe my feelings about the current state of SO -
**dissapointed**, **frustrated** and eventually **disgusted**.

1. [How to use enum class without a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794789/how-to-use-enum-class-without-a-scope) was about enum classes in C++11.

   Lets omit the fact that it got downvoted without any explanation from any user or moderator. It is not vague, nor duplicate, nor a homework, and even shows some effort from my side to conquer the problem.

   It asks a very clearly defined and specific question about a real programming problem I bumped into. I needed to use RED instead of Color::RED in one of my member functions, but only allow this for the single function.

   I got two useless suggestions. Then the user realized he misinterpreted my question. The answer concludes I should use a regular enum, which I was trying to avoid in the first place.

   Needless to say, the obvious answer that I eventually have chosen (namespaces) was not even mentioned.

   The answer was **not accepted**.
2. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934231/is-customer-calls-support-centre-a-use-case, I was having a conversation about a UML use case diagram with a person that have mistaken the subject (system boundary) for the subject (grammar). No comment on that.

   I won't even bother explaining why his answer was off-topic.

   The answer was **not accepted**.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118859/open-pdf-with-foxit-outside-of-the-browser *might* be considered a bit off-topic on SO.

   But if so, why is it not downvoted? Why is it not closed? Why am I not noticed it is off-topic? Why am I not suggested the correct place to post this question?

   This question was **not even answered**
4. In [Sum the odd positioned and the even positioned integers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160424/sum-the-odd-positioned-and-the-even-positioned-integers-in-an-array) I got downvoted for an unclear (and eventually incorrect) question. I admit I deserved it, although I have improved my question considerably as soon as I was noticed.

   The answer is correct.

   The answer **was accepted**.
5. [Can a pure abstract class contain static constants, static methods or non-virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197720/can-a-pure-abstract-class-contain-static-constants-static-methods-or-non-virtua) is a very basic question about the notion of a "pure abstract class" in C++.

   The comments say, there is no definition of "pure abstract class" in the C++ standard (or possibly TC++PL). I concur.

   However, I have included a definition from *another* source in my question and was asking if the class I defined in the question was pure abstract according to *this* definition.

   It seems my question did not even get read! I even included four relevant sources and bulletproof arguments to make it clear I did my research.

   The question was **not even answered**

To **sum it up**, **only 1 of 5 of my questions was answered and accepted**. The other were not even close to being accepted, if there was at least anything to accept, of course!

What is interesting is there were over 200 users that visited these 5 questions over a period of 4 weeks. Considering how basic my questions were, under the assumption they are motivated to answer I can only conclude they did not know the answer.

Now we might have a discussion on what is wrong with Stack Overflow. I have another question, though.

**What are the alternatives?**

Comment: I would like you to prove me, the problem with these 5 questions was on my side of the line and not on SO's. Unless you do that, I would like an answer to the last question. Frankly, I would like the answer to it anyway.

Comment: It sounds like you're disappointed in part because you didn't get what you considered adequate answers to four of your five questions. One possible solution would be adding a bounty to those questions to attract additional attention, and hopefully an answer that you consider satisfactory.

Comment: I explained the reasons why everyone should consider the answers inadequate. I might use a bounty. The first problem is I don't have enough reputation to give away on each question I ask. The second problem is I never had to care about "bounty" until now. My questions got answered timely and perfectly. If I used bounty, it was on a question I wanted a more comprehensive and elaborate answer for. And I think that should be the purpose of bounty.

Comment: The problem simply is I do not get useful answers (if any) to my questions anymore. I want to know why. Is it my fault? Am I doing something wrong? Or where is the problem?

Comment: Why feel disappoint to the site? I think, at least, it is not the fault of this site or moderator as they cannot control how many users can answer your questions.

Comment: I feel disappointed, because it used to work before. My questions got answered and accepted in a matter of minutes. And I never had to use a bounty. Now I wait a month with no result.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have enough reputation for a bounty? You have 888 points, that's enough for a 50 point bounty on each question, without losing any privileges.

Comment: Asking 5 questions a month, I would run out of points in three months.

Comment: *What are the alternatives?* - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Well it was rather a rhetorical question. I was implying I wanted to leave SO for good. Now I see its better to solve the problems than to run from them.

Comment: @Slazer Well consider answering so many questions and gaining upvotes that you earn enough points to give away in bounties?

Comment: @Tim I will not answer a question unless I fully understand the topic. I will especially not do this for points only. My reputation suggests I have a lot to learn, so I ask questions instead. The fact they are downvoted also suggests I am not ready for answering. Even if I did answer, please tell me where can a beginner like me gather 5*50=250 points a month?

Comment: @Slazer well you can get 200 a day (that's the limit). I am on the python tag - consider finding a tag you know a little about?

Comment: @Tim I just found out I get 10 points (not 2) for an upvote to my answer (15 if accepted). So that's how one gains points on this site :). I need 1 upvote a day to ask 6 questions per month with 50 rep bounty. That's kind of achievable. My reputation would increase very slowly, though.

Comment: The questions with the c++ tag are too complicated. Is there a way to limit it to questions from users with reputation lower than mine?

Comment: @Slazer Probably not, but even so, if *I* were to ask a question in C++ it might be something you could answer. I've got 3 times the rep you do, but that's from answering *javascript* questions!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Of the 5 questions, I've found some correctable issues with 3 of them, and skipped 1.

#### [Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794789/how-to-use-enum-class-without-a-scope)

There's no explanation about what you're trying to accomplish with this. What's the end goal? Since you're asking about something that is apparently impossible, adding information about the desired end result would give people an opportunity to provide alternatives.

Also, your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794789/how-to-use-enum-class-without-a-scope#comment53428475_32795072) on the answer says:

> Moreover I cant use that in a switch statement like I wanted to.

But you didn't mention that in the question. The person answering the question can only answer using the information you give them.

#### [Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934231/is-customer-calls-support-centre-a-use-case)

> I won't even bother explaining why his answer was off-topic.

In that case, we'll skip this question then. I don't know enough about [uml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uml) to know whether the answer isn't an answer for your question, and I suspect that a lot of people reading this don't either.

#### [Question #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118859/open-pdf-with-foxit-outside-of-the-browser)

> But if so, why is it not downvoted? Why is it not closed? Why am I not noticed it is off-topic? Why am I not suggested the correct place to post this question?

It's probably not been closed as off topic yet because it's a quiet set of tags on the question. You also have enough reputation that your questions don't go into automatic reviews. With almost 900 reputation the onus is on you to know what's on-topic here.

Additionally, sometimes these things take time. I've corrected that now by flagging it as off topic, because

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.** You may be able to get help on Super User.

(Emphasis Mine)

*(Hint: When asking something like that, the OS/platform is important.)*

#### [Question #4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160424/sum-the-odd-positioned-and-the-even-positioned-integers-in-an-array)

Glad you eventually got an answer, but the 30+ comments under the suggest that the question may have been confusingly worded. Some people spent a considerable amount of time trying to help you, so you can't really be surprised that the current score is sitting at -4, can you? Assume for every one person that comments to try to help improve the question, 10 other people have also seen it.

#### [Question #5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197720/can-a-pure-abstract-class-contain-static-constants-static-methods-or-non-virtua)

Nice question as far as I can tell.  If I found the question naturally, rather than from a link on meta, you'd probably have even gotten a vote from me.

You did only ask it 13 hours ago. It's Sunday. People spend time with their families on Sunday. Give it a week. The effort to answer this is non-trivial.

Also, it's important to remember that we get 10k+ questions a day, so sometimes things get lost in the shuffle. Sorry, but it is what it is. We try not to, but it happens. Of all the questions you've asked about, this is the one that may be worth a bounty if it gets lost in the shuffle. (If it were me, I'd offer +100, and ask for an authoritative answer citing the specification where possible.)

Comment: Very nice answer. Comprehensive and constructive. I think I will accept it in the morning. I will have to think about the bounty system. Could you please also explain what was/is wrong about my question on meta SO (this question)? I lost 10 reputation on SO and -9 here so far because of it...

Comment: @Slazer - You don't lose any reputation due to votes on Meta posts.

Comment: Not sure if you are a beginner, but to remind you that posting your questions to meta may attract more downvotes

Comment: @Slazer I guess Meta is a bit trigger-happy with anything that looks even remotely like one of the many incoming "My totally on-topic question about licking toads got closed by Nazi moderators!!!! Stack Overflow sux!!!!!!" questions. (Not saying yours is one of them.)

Comment: @Slazer yeah I also can not see the reason for so many down votes. I am also worried about the state of other "soft issue" in SO, the more i use it.

Comment: @Slazer - You could probably write a 1000 page dissertation on meta voting, but it boils down to: voting on meta is weird. Downvotes here sometimes are agreement/disagreement, sometimes about perceived effort, sometimes like Pekka said, just random trigger happiness. Related is the [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/5240004). Thanks for taking this for the constructive criticism it was meant to be.  A lot of people that end up here asking about why their questions don't get attention and upvotes don't take criticism well.

Comment: @Seabizkit What do you mean by "soft issue"? I am a bit slow :).

Comment: @Slazer - If I had to guess I'd say [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307861/what-is-my-mistake-here/307864#comment258389_307864).

Comment: @theB, and Slazer, yip, the issue is bigger than I'm suggesting but would require me to write an essay. Basically, rude,none mature and not so knowledgeable, arrogant people can end up with SO scores over 10 000. The more I use SO this becomes very apparent. BUT with that said, there are some awesome people too. But to many kiddies, thinking they are the $hit, and not taking constructive criticism well...

Comment: @Seabizkit - Yep and so can people like Eric Lippert.  This is tangental to slazer's question, and I've already voiced my opinion about this. No need to hijack this question.

Comment: @theB "No need to hijack this question" FYI i am not at all! don't know how you got that. i'm sorry i didn't know others were not allowed to voice their opinions.

Comment: @Seabizkit - Never did I say that you couldn't express your opinion. What I said is [I've already voiced my opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308262/analysis-to-ascertain-the-experience-level-of-stack-overflow-posters-and-moderat/308264#308264). If you want to start a discussion you're more than welcome to start your own.

Answer (score 10):

There are all sorts of reasons why questions might not get answered on Stack Overflow:

- The question is unclear so folks don't know how to answer
- The question is clear, but nobody who reads the question knows how to answer
- The question is clear and one or more visitors who knows the answer, but they don't have the time or inclination to write it up
- ...

Many clear, well-formed, on-topic questions don't get answered just because they are hard or because the asker got unlucky (the right eyeballs didn't find their question).

> What are the alternatives?

One approach to get more eyeballs on your questions and incentivize answers would be to create a bounty on them as a form of advertisement. Bounties drive views and encourage those who visit to answer, so that could be a good investment if you're finding you can't get answers to your questions without them.